# How to use Flway to migrate utPLSQL into a DB?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, flyway

I've got utPLSQL installed on my dev database (Oracle 11xe) in a user schema where it can execute my unit test suite. (I've got a Flyway location for my product code migration scripts and a Flyway location for my test code migration scripts.) To run unit tests in a clean DB I have to manually execute utplsql's install script using sqlplus: "@ut_i_do install"), then my flyway migrations (product code and unit test code) happen with one command. I want to automate that install. How do I create a Flyway migration script that will install utPLSQL along with my test code?

Comment: I tried a lot of different ways of calling ut_i_do.sql install from a migration script but keep erroring out when flyway does the migration. Many variations of     `Begin
 execute 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\utplsql-2-3-0\code\ut_i_do.sql install';
end;`  With and without Begins, "@".  It's finding and executing the script but there is something causing a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

The install routine uses some functionality that's specific to SQL*Plus, so needs to be invoked by that. I'm not familiar with Flyway, but it sounds like it's not handling the SQL*Plus specific functionality.

Do you have anyway to execute an OS command from Flyway that would run SQL*Plus and call the installer as a parameter maybe?

Comment: I see.  Flyway command line does some logic to decide what SQL scripts need to be executed. The idea is to let Flyway handle decision making what sql scripts to execute.  So I should be able to point Flyway to an empty Oracle instance and install everything. So this is why I want to automate the installation of utPLSQL via a SQL script.  Maybe I can launch SQL*Plus from a SQL script...  Maybe SQL scripts can execute OS commands such as SQLPlus...  Or maybe build a SQL script version of the utPLSQL installation.  You've made clear what the problem is. Thank you Paul.